# How to reset a previously selected row and highlight a new row in JQGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a row1 selected and highlighted then am selecting row2 getting highlighted; when i select row2 i want only row2 highlighted with css and row1 should be defaulted or may be for row1 i want to remove css.  Please help

```
onSelectRow: function(id){
              var rowData = $(this).getRowData(id); 
              var memberId= rowData['memberId'];//replace name with any column

              if(id!==lastSel){ 


                 $(this).find('.ui-state-highlight').css({background:'#80BFFF'});
                 lastSel=id; 

                }

        }
```

Comment: jqGrid handles selection automatically - is there a reason why the default behavior is not working for you?

Comment: You are correct! it does selection and resetselection automatically; but when i select a row I want a different css color coding; so when am doing that; reset happens but i want to remove the color which am setting upon selection.

Comment: helpful link https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/jqgrid-reset-row-selction-when-clicked-outside-or-lost-focus-or-onblur/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you are actually modifying the CSS of the "selected" row.  In order to properly remove the "selected" highlight of the previously selected element, you would have to also remove the css modification.  I would suggest putting your highlight color in a selected class, and then add/remove based on that:

**CSS**

```
.selected{
background-color:#80BFFF !important;
}
```

**JS**

```
onSelectRow: function(id){
          var rowData = $(this).getRowData(id); 
          var memberId= rowData['memberId'];//replace name with any column

          if(id!==lastSel){
             $(this).find(".selected").removeClass('selected');
             $('#results_table').jqGrid('resetSelection', lastSel, true);

             $(this).find('.ui-state-highlight').addClass('selected');
             lastSel=id; 

            }

    }
```